# How to change a read-only table parameter in method?

Tags: abap

I'm trying to enhance the class **CL_FB_MMPUR_SUBCON**, method **USER_COMMAND** for ME2ON transaction, so as to control the data changed by the user to create a delivery.

The issue is that I can't modify the import `IT_OUTTAB` table, because it's just **Read Only**
[image]

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the lock for this internal table so as i can update it?

Comment: The class you mention is a fallback class of the BAdI `ME_BADI_SUBCON_IBS`. Don't you just want to implement that BAdI? There's the method `EXTEND_OUTTAB` to change the "out table".

Comment: We can't implement the BAdI ME_BADI_SUBCON_IBS because it's reserved for SAP for any upgrade.
However the methode EXTEND_OUTTAB it's called just in the first displaying of the ALV, and not after a user change.

Answer (score 2):

`IT_OUTTAB` is an IMPORTING parameter of the method so a READ-ONLY flag is automatically set and **cannot be unset** inside the method. Check the method which calls the method, maybe the passed variable is modifiable there, or search elsewhere, where the original data is modifiable...

Answer (score 2):

`IMPORTING` parameter can ONLY be changed if it is passed by `VALUE`.

[image]

You need to implement a METHOD with `CHANGING` or reference parameters for your intended data input/output.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTING paramter IV_UCOMM is read only and  CL_FB_MMPUR_SUBCON is a standard class.You have too look for an alternate solution. If you want to control data changed then you to find BAdi or exit for the transaction ME2ON.